# An exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Hi Im having problem quoted as below

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'admin' to data type int.

I'm having difficulty understanding what the problem is as I don't have the 'admin' value.

My code in asp.net

```
             String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBcon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("useraddorupdate", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aspLOGINID", (HFLOGINID.Value == 
             "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(HFLOGINID.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aspFULLNAME", 
 TxtFullname.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aspULOGIN", 
 Txtuserlogin.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aspLOGROLEID", 
 Convert.ToInt32(DplLoginrole.SelectedValue));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aspPASSWORDHASH", 
 TxtPassword.Text.Trim());
            con.Open();
            string LoginID = HFLOGINID.Value;
            int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (ReturnCode == -1)
              {
                LblErrorMESSAGE.Text = "User Name Already in use, Please choose another User name";
              }
            else if (LoginID == "")
              {

                 LblsuccessMessage.Text = "New User saved Successfully!";
              }
            else
              {
                 LblsuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully!";
              }
                 Fillgridview();
        }

    }
```

here is my stored procedure

```
    Alter proc useraddorupdate
    @aspLOGINID int,
    @aspFULLNAME varchar(50),
    @aspULOGIN NVARCHAR(50),
    @aspLOGROLEID INT,
    @aspPASSWORDHASH NVARCHAR(50)
    AS
     BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @COUNT INT
    DECLARE @RETURNCODE INT


   BEGIN
    IF (@aspLOGINID = 0)
          BEGIN
        SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(Ulogin)
        FROM ULoginInfo WHERE ULogin = @aspLOGINID
        IF @COUNT > 0
          BEGIN
        SET @RETURNCODE = -1
          END
        ELSE
          BEGIN
        SET @RETURNCODE = 1
        INSERT INTO ULoginInfo (Fullname, Ulogin, LogRoleID, 
                    PasswordHash)VALUES (@aspFULLNAME, @aspULOGIN, 
                    @aspLOGROLEID, @aspPASSWORDHASH)
          END
    END
    ELSE
       BEGIN
         Set @ReturnCode = 1
         UPDATE ULoginInfo
         SET PasswordHash = @aspPASSWORDHASH)
         WHERE LoginID = @aspLOGINID
       END
    Select @RETURNCODE as ReturnValue
       END
    
 END
```

Comment: You cant convert the string "'admin" to an integer!!!

Comment: Can you post the table definition for `ULoginInfo`?

Comment: Do you have 'admin' value in connection string? In which line it shows exception? Or do you have any role set as admin (@aspLOGROLEID INT)

Comment: I think it's happening at `WHERE ULogin = @aspLOGINID`.  Did you mean `WHERE LoginID = @aspLOGINID` like you did on the `UPDATE`?

Comment: @jdweng Hi sir that's my problem as i don't have "admin" value.

Comment: @JohnWu Hi Sir here it is LoginID pk int not null
Fullname varchar(50) not null,
Ulogin varchar(50) not null,
LogRoleID INT not null,
Passwordhash varchar(50) not null

Comment: Hi @madreflection THANK YOU unfortunately it should be '@aspULOGIN' my problem is solved.

Comment: That makes sense, too. You're welcome.